# Get center of vtkImageReslice

Tags: vtk

How can I retrieve the center of a vtkImageReslice object ? Here is my trial, it doesn't working:

```
vtkImageData* pImageData = m_pReslice->GetOutput();
double dCenter[2];
pImageData->GetCenter(dCenter);
```

after that, I want to use dCenter value to made a translate by vtkTransform ...

Regards,
Flaviu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can calculate the center of your imagedata.

```
CenterX = OriginX + PixelSpacingX * 0.5 * ImageWidth
CenterY = OriginY + PixelSpacingY * 0.5 * ImageHeight
CenterZ = OriginZ + PixelSpacingZ * 0.5 * ImageDepth
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I know how to find origins:

```
double dOrigin[3];
pImageData->GetOrigin(dOrigin);
```

and spacing:

```
double dSpacing[3];
pImageData->GetSpacing(dSpacing);
```

but how can I find ImmageWidth, ImageHeight and ImageDepth ?

Comment: e.g. `pImageData->GetDimension(dDimension);`

Comment: Is any reason why a CT series, read by vtkDICOMImageReader, have spacing 0, on z axis ?